# Windows Service - Restart itself?

Tags: windows, service, restart

I need to put some code to restart my Windows Service when faces a critical error (big story)

I have this function

```
public Boolean RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        try
        {
            int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
            service.Stop();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
            int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
            if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException ex)
        {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The thing is that it is obviously not good because although it Stops...it cannot Start again :)

Is there a way to re-construct it in such way that it can "remember" to Start itself?

Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a service is stopped it is stopped. It doesn't run anymore, so no more code is being executed.

There in my opinion two ways you can achieve this: Windows is able to re-start services upon fatal errors itself. All you need to do is the following:

Set the service to restart after failure (double click the service in the control panel). If you want the service to restart, just call `Environment.Exit(1);` (or any non-zero return) and the OS will restart it for you.

Another way would be to write a service monitor service that checks whether the service is stopped and then restarts it.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten!! But where exactly should I put the Environment.Exit(1); code?

Comment: Well, at what point in your code did you intend to call your non-functional `RestartService` method? There! :-) You could also replace the content of your `RestartService` method with `Environment.Exit(1)` and remove the parameters from the method declaration. In case you do not catch the exception that makes you want to restart the service, it will work anyway, because in that case the service stop unexpectedly and the system will restart it also due to the first configuration step.